# Adding a library to cmake

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake

I am trying to compile my project with a library called [SDL_draw](http://sdl-draw.sourceforge.net/) using cmake . 
After i download and install it the library files goes to /usr/local/lib and is named libSDL_draw.a ,so i edited the CMakeLists.txt to read this .

```
link_directories(
    /usr/local/lib
)
include_directories(/usr/local/lib)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(point_trajectory point_trajectory.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(point_trajectory SDL_draw)
```

The cmake succeeds but when i "make" the project after cmake it still cannot find SDL_draw.h .

```
fatal error: SDL_draw.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/point_trajectory.dir/point_trajectory.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/point_trajectory.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used SDL_draw before, but something looks funny.  Usually the library archive is in /usr/local/lib but the header file is somewhere else ... probably /usr/local/include .

You might want to double-check where SDL_draw.h is.  If it is in /usr/local/lib, then double-check that you installed it correctly.

Possibly, this will fix your problem:

```
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
```

Comment: SDL_draw.h is not present anywhere in the usr directory .

Comment: I put the SDL_draw.h in /usr/local/include and it seems to work .

Comment: For what it's worth, you might want to read the documentation for SDL_draw.  In particular, there should be an installation step which copies SDL_draw.h for you into /usr/local/include.  Of course, doing a copy manually also works, but this might be a sign that something else could be wrong.  So, you might want to look into it just in case of any future problems.